# Repainting on google chrome lag and glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, repaint

On the page http://bit.ly/1t9P8jS, when we scoll down the page, the fixed menu background color glitch. This bug occurs only on Google Chrome.

I change the Z-index, changed the .on('scroll') to a function on requestAnimationFrame, nothing repair it.

You can scroll down where it has 10 logos and go over the menu, you will see it.

What can cause this? Why it's only on google chrome? I never saw a background-color glitching like this.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It also seems to be only Chrome on Windows, not OSX. I've seen Chrome have other repaint glitches, but not this bad before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `.loader` to `display:none;` this fixed it for me. (Chrome 38 on Win)

For whatever reason, Chrome must be confused by the zindex and opacity combination when deciding what to repaint.
It should be pretty easy to hide/show your loader instead of just changing the opacity.